# has apple removed pflog from packetfilter?

Tags: firewall

FreeBSD includes `pflog` as a way to analyze `pf` logs. I dont see a `/var/log/pflog`. Has MacOS removed the `pflog` and `/var/log/pflog`?

Is it possible to enable this?

Answer (score 2):

From the pflog(4) man page:

```
Create a pflog interface and monitor all packets logged on it:

       # ifconfig pflog1 create
       # tcpdump -n -e -ttt -i pflog1
```